# How should I choose a free variable in parametric form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix} * x = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

What's the next step? 1 or 2? And why?

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix} * x = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix} * x = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

What's the algorithm of choosing free variable?
If I choose x2 as a free variable, I get the right answer x = (-1, 1, -1), **but why x2, not x1?**

Comment: What makes you think you can't choose $x_1$ as the free variable?  Have you tried?

Comment: Ummm... $x = (0,0,0)^t$, perhaps?